# Unable to fetch data of internal Gitlab from Azure Devops (getting Git fetch failed with exit code: 128)

Tags: azure-devops, gitlab, azure-pipelines

My scenario is quite basic. Let me try to explain:

1. I do have **an on-premise instance of Gitlab behind the firewalls of
   my company**
2. And I am trying to fetch data from a pipeline set on **Azure Devops
   (dev.azure.com)**

I am getting this error when queuing a job run

```
##[error]Git fetch failed with exit code: 128
```

The IT security folks ask for an IP to Whitelist as INBOUND, but I have no clue what range I should give them.

Anyone faced such situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If as what your IT security asked and you used is hosted agent, the ip range should be the one which can grant the hosted agents access through a firewall.

Follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops#agent-ip-ranges):

> To determine your geography, navigate to
>   https://dev.azure.com//_settings/organizationOverview,
>   get your region, and find the associated geography from the Azure
>   geography table. Once you have identified your [geography](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/geographies/), use the
>   IP ranges from the [weekly file](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519) for all regions in that geography.

---